# JQuery UI Slider inside Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

My [JQuery UI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) widget doesn't show up inside a Modal, it does show in normal content though.

[HERE'S THE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNecCItRBLNwBAX6pSJm)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

 <head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <span>SLIDER?</span>
        <div class="slider"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>


  <div>
  <span>SLIDER OK</span>
  <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavasCript

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  $scope.open = function(size) {

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
     animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
     templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
     controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
     size: size,
     resolve: {
       items: function() {
       return $scope.items;
      }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {

}, function() {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};
});


angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {



$scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
$(function() {
    $(".slider").slider();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the slider is created when the page loads instead of when the modal is open. Then the slider is created at the beginning and fails when in the modal.

A posssible solution would be to create the slider when the modal opens (and specifying in the selector that it will be the slider inside the modal, otherwise it seems that jQuery will create a slider also for the code in the template).

Here is a demo modifying your original code as little as possible (I moved the slider creation to the function that opens and renders the modal):

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function(size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.rendered.then( function() {
      $(".modal-body .slider").slider()
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
    
  };



});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span>SLIDER?</span>
        <div class="slider"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>

    <div>
      <span>Slider OK</span>
      <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not mix [AngularJS Directives for bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and JQUERYUI, so I kept JQuery UI modal and slider:

[Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8oLy8PcymoLU1KCVA0d?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
 <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>dialog demo</title>
 <button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
 <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog
 <div id="slider"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 $("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
 });
$("#opener").click(function() {
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
$("#slider").slider();
});
});
```